# Changing date format in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, date, format

I have just created a date field attribute.

In `Proprieties > Fields` of the layer I made this:

[image: Result1]

And the attribute tables shows this:

[image: Result2]

What I want to see is the date in this format: `07-01-2019` and not `2019-01-27`.

What do I need to do to have a permanent solution?

Comment: That's how date are stored in the field. You can enter your data in edit mode as DD-MM-YYYY and If you identify the point, the data will be seen as DD-MM-YYYY

Answer (score 6):

Bring back `Field Format` to default (`yyyy-MM-dd`) setting and customize the `Widget Display` only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It works when you have QGIS opened, but if you remove and add your layer the format change to the default format.

Comment: @PauloMartinho If you need a permanent change in the date display setting, make sure to state it in your question.